# Find out column having null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to find out which column having null value in a entire table. In table schema all columns has allows null but in table only few columns having null how to figure out those columns .

I tried with Collate function (Select * from Table_name where COLLATE(column1,column2,...columnN) IS NULL it shows syntax error near collate

I want to find out which column data having null value in a table

Comment: `select min(col_1), min(col_2), ... from mytable)` and see for which columns the result is null.

Comment: `MIN` is an aggregate function and omits `NULL` values, @ThorstenKettner , it'll only return `NULL` if *all* values are `NULL` not if they have at least a single `NULL` value.

Comment: @Thom A: This is how I have understood "having null value in a entire table". But maybe I have misinterpreted this.

Comment: @Abi: Please clarify. Detect columns with null in at least one row or with null in all rows?

Comment: I can see that, @ThorstenKettner . The prior statement *"In table schema all columns has allows null but in table only few columns having null how to figure out those columns"* lead me to think that they want to identify their `NULL`able columns, even though they are all defined that it. The language is somewhat unclear. Seems the OP needs to [edit] their question to clarify the problem.

Comment: You mean `COALESCE()`.

Comment: @ThomA -- Detect columns with null in at least one row

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

I think if you try to use `COALESCE` instead of `COLLATE`,
since `COALESCE(att1, att2, att3)` return the first value that is not null, your code will return all rows where *everything* is `NULL`.

You can try to return every rows where there's a `NULL` value :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE
    col1 IS NULL
    OR col2 IS NULL
    OR ...
```

or for every column, you count the non-null values :

```
SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(col1), COUNT(col2), ...
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Every `COUNT(colX)` with a different value than `COUNT(*)` contains `NULL` values

Comment: `COALESCE` is very likely to generate a conversion error, unless the OP has also foolishly defined all their columns as the same data type.

Comment: @ThomA you are right !

Answer (score 0):

Use this to figure out which columns have at least one null value:

```
DECLARE @col_name VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @table_name VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @schema_name VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(500)


SET @table_name ='yourtable'
SET @schema_name ='yourschema'

DECLARE columns CURSOR FOR
  select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
  where TABLE_NAME =@table_name and TABLE_SCHEMA =@schema_name

OPEN columns  
FETCH NEXT FROM columns INTO @col_name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    set @sql = 'if exists(SELECT * from '+@schema_name+'.'+@table_name+' where '+@col_name+' is null) select '''+@col_name+''' '
    exec (@sql) 
    

FETCH NEXT FROM columns INTO @col_name  
END 

CLOSE columns  
DEALLOCATE columns
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic way to determine columns that have NULL values in all rows in a table.

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpTable;

CREATE TABLE #tmpTable (
     client_id int,
     client_name varchar(500),
     client_surname varchar(500),
     city varchar(500),
     state varchar(500));
    
INSERT #tmpTable VALUES
(1,'Miriam',NULL,'Las Vegas',NULL),
(2,'Astrid',NULL,'Chicago',NULL),
(3,'David',NULL,'Phoenix',NULL),
(4,'Hiroki',NULL,'Orlando',NULL);

SELECT name 
FROM tempdb.sys.columns
WHERE object_id = object_id('tempdb..#tmpTable')
    AND is_nullable = 1
EXCEPT
SELECT x.value('local-name(.)', 'SYSNAME')
FROM #tmpTable AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(c)
    CROSS APPLY c.nodes('/root/*') AS t2(x);
```

**Output**

| name |
| --- |
| client_surname |
| state |

Comment: Getting output as name alone.

Comment: You continue to communicate in riddles. Please see my comment under your original question. Please edit your original question and provide a **minimal reproducible example**.